# Disable dashboard when not authorized

Tags: react-admin

This question is specific for: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin

My App.js look like that:

```
<Admin
        customSagas={[ errorSagas ]}
        loginPage={LoginPage}
        authProvider={authProvider}
        dataProvider={dataProvider}
      >
        <Resource name="topics" create={TopicCreate} list={TopicsList} show={TopicShow} />
        <Resource name="clients" create={ClientCreate} list={ClientsList} show={ClientShow} />
        <Resource name="genders"/>
        <Resource name="interests-in"/>
      </Admin>
```

If I'm not logged in and I go to `/topics` I got 401 and I redirected to `/login`.

If I'm logged in and I go to `/blabla` I get the Dashboard and Menu which is security issue.

1. I don't want that non-authorized user will be able to view the dashboard and the menu.
2. When I view the "source" of the page I can see all paths (URLS) to my admin api. It should be disabled as well.

[image]

How to avoid this kind of situations? someone help?
Lior

Comment: Guys I just want to explain that I'm going to have more security layers as "2 auth factor" and "IP restrictions" but still I think we need to get some answers about that 2 questions.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can think of would be to check for your security items inside the component where you are rendering the `Admin`. If your security checks fails, then don't even render the `Admin`.

Comment: What about using "Declaring resources at runtime" and the request must includes JWT token which is secured.

Comment: You mean using the `<Admin>` children as a function pattern ? https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Authorization.html#restricting-access-to-resources-or-views

Comment: Nope, it is still not secured because all resources are printed on the HTML and everyone can see the menu and the "paths". I meant: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Admin.html#declaring-resources-at-runtime which will select all resources from the server-side after login with the JWT token. What do u think mate?